# Remove old 1.0.1 CouchDB databases

Tags: couchdb

I've installed CouchDB on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but the default version was 1.0.1.

After removal and installation of new version, 1.6, I have some old databases in my CouchDB:
1.0.1/_users etc.

I cannot delete them, as I'm not allowed to call commands on databases starting with numbers etc.

How can I completely remove them?

This is my command and output:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://127.0.0.1:5984/1.0.1/_users"
{"error":"illegal_database_name","reason":"Name: '1.0.1'. Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."}
```

Comment: I've tried to delete /var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1/, seems to work, but the 1.0.1-databases still appear in the recent databases overview.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the folder containing the old databases on the filesystem itself under /var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1

e.g.

```
rm -r /var/lib/couchdb/1.0.1
```

I don't believe it is possible from within couch/futon.